# How to calculate the nearest hundred in android?

Tags: android

I have implemented a Bar chart for File Manager mobile app. I have to show used space on Y-Axis.

Is there any way to calculate the nearest hundred of max value?

Comment: Since you're using it on an axis you presumably want to [always round _up_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double)) so that all of the graph fits, no?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, You are right nearest hundred concept is wrong.. please tell me what can I do to plot the y-axis value based on max value of directory size.

Comment: To always round up, change `size+50` in Ted's answer to `size+99` if it's an integer. If it's a decimal, use something like `100.0*Math.ceil(size/100)`.

Comment: Thank You, it is help full..

Answer (score 3):

Just thought I'd add this as an alternative; since you want to still fit the whole graph inside the axis, you'll probably want to always round *up to the next greater 100*, not to the nearest 100.

To do this for a double, just use [`Math.ceil`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double)), for regular rounding [`Math.round`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double));

```
double value = 8239;

double rounded_up = 100 * Math.ceil(value / 100);
System.out.println(rounded_up);

> 8300.0

double rounded_closest = 100 * Math.round(value / 100.0);
System.out.println(rounded_closest);

> 8200.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
int size = . . .;
int nearestHundred = 100 * ((size + 50) / 100);
```

Explanation: dividing by 100 truncates to the largest integer less than or equal to the quotient. Multiplying by 100 scales the quotient back to the desired units. By adding 50 before dividing, the effect is to round to the nearest 100 rather than truncating to the largest multiple of 100. (For example, 149 becomes 100, but 150 becomes 200.)

Comment: could u explain a lil bit.. what will it do? why are u multiplying with 199?

Comment: @Tarun - Explanation added :)

Comment: @Tarun - The 199? Yeah. Fixed.